# C# Unity Photon выход игрока

Tags: c#, unity3d

Если персонаж касается объекта с тегом "ат" он отключался, но почему-то отключается другой игрок

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "At")
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ну, вероятно, стоит получить нужный скрипт у `collision.gameObject` и уже у него вызвать `PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom()`

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка у вас на игроке есть скрипт `PhotonView`.

Вы объявляете его:

```
PhotonView pv;
```

В старте получаете:

```
pv = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
```

А в OnCollisionEnter2D проверяете свойство `isMain, так как каждый игрок должен выйти сам. Вот метод:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (pv.isMain && collision.gameObject.tag == "At")
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```